# Custom Fields for Images in Salesforce

Tags: images

I am aware that Salesforce doesn't have a field type of 'Image' and that to tie an image to a record, you're most likely going to upload it somewhere (could be in Salesforce Files tab, could be external) and then store the image's url in a custom field on an object.

Are there any reference applications and/or commonly used App Exchange packages that either implement this process or demonstrate best practices for how to simplify this process so that end users don't have to manually enter URL's but can instead do something like pop open a window, upload an image, and have it all taken care of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you would like to populate a object field with the url of the related attachment/file that has been uploaded.  One could write an apex trigger that examines the attachment / file object and populates the required field(s) on the related object.  This would require being able to define this process through code.

Comment: thanks, Benjamin. That approach makes sense.